# ng-repeat doesn't work on one item

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have a JSON array object that I'm doing an AngularJS ng-repeat on, the following code works when breed and/or option has more than one object, but not when they only have one object, in fact doing pet.breeds.breed[0] or pet.options.option[0] doesn't return anything when those objects only have one object

```js
        "pet": {
            "options": {
                "option": [{
                    "$t": "hasShots"
                }]
            },
            "status": {
                "$t": "A"
            },
            "contact": {
                "phone": {},
                "state": {
                    "$t": "NC"
                },
                "address2": {},
                "email": {
                    "$t": "deborah@rainingpets.com"
                },
                "city": {
                    "$t": "Charlotte"
                },
                "zip": {
                    "$t": "28210"
                },
                "fax": {},
                "address1": {}
            },
            "age": {
                "$t": "Adult"
            },
            "size": {
                "$t": "L"
            },
            "id": {
                "$t": "37778045"
            },
            "shelterPetId": {},
            "breeds": {
                "breed": {
                    "$t": "German Shepherd Dog"
                }
            },
            "name": {
                "$t": "Axel"
            },
            "sex": {
                "$t": "M"
            },
            "description": {
                "$t": "Axel is a handsome 4-year-old German Shepherd who is looking for a home. He is a large boy weighing 95 pounds but should be closer to 80. He has the GSD prey drive and would do best with someone who is experienced with the breed. Axel is a typical Shepherd; loving, loyal and good with children. He is also playful and does need a fenced yard to play in.\n\nAxel is vaccinated, neutered and micro-chipped."
            },
            "mix": {
                "$t": "no"
            },
            "shelterId": {
                "$t": "NC880"
            },
            "lastUpdate": {
                "$t": "2017-04-08T19:31:08Z"
            },
            "animal": {
                "$t": "Dog"
            }
        }
```

```html
 <div class="ui label" ng-repeat="(k, breed) in pet.breeds.breed">{{breed.$t}}</div>
```

Comment: what does `breeds` property look like when more than one exists? Also do you control the structure of the data sent from server?

Comment: You should always return **breeds** value as an array, even if there is only one entity for it, like this  **"breeeds":[{first breed object}]**. I can not format in this comment the json object. So, I hope you understood what I want to say

Comment: I have no control over the data being sent from the server
this is what breeds looks like with more than one item:
            "breeds": {
                "breed": [{
                    "$t": "Siamese"
                }, {
                    "$t": "Himalayan"
                }]
            }

Comment: If you will provide further details, like how you are populating the JSON response, I mean lile PHP backend or Java etc. I will be able to help further

Comment: Okay, ng-repeat only works with array. In this case you will have to convert it to array, by yourself. Or you will have to add a check if the breeds object is an array or plain object, using **angular.isArray()**. If the breeds object is an array, use ng-repeat logic, otherwise use direct key access like, breeds.breed.$t

Comment: @KamalSingh not true...can pass object to `ng-repeat` and use object syntax as per docs

Comment: @charlieetfl you can offcourse pass an object to ng-repeat, but it should be a collection to work properly. Here are the best use cases of ng-repeat https://blog.rjmetrics.com/2015/09/02/8-features-of-ng-repeat/ . If you want to iterate over keys of the object than, it is Okay to pass a plain object

Comment: @KamalSingh was simply responding to your inaccurate statement above ... *"Okay, ng-repeat only works with array"*. I already know how it works without needing a tutorial link

Answer (score 1):

you can use `angular.isArray` for check it.

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = { 
        "pet": {
            "breeds": {
                "breed": { "$t": "Siamese" }
             }   
          }
       }
       
       $scope.isArray = angular.isArray($scope.data.pet.breeds.breed);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="form-group">
 <div class="ui label" ng-if="isArray" ng-repeat="(k, breed) in data.pet.breeds.breed">{{breed.$t}}</div>
 
 <div class="ui label" ng-if="!isArray" ng-repeat="(k, breed) in data.pet.breeds">{{breed.$t}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that if more than one exists the structure of `breeds.breed` is array and is object for only one you will be best off mapping the data to consistent array structure before passing to view

Something like:

```
$http.get('path/to/api').then(function(res){
  var pet = res.data.pet;
  if(angular.isArray(pet.breeds.breed) ){
     // already an array
     $scope.breeds = pet.breeds.breed;
   }else{
     // put object in new array
     $scope.breeds = [pet.breeds.breed];
   }
})
```

Then in view:

```
<div class="ui label" ng-repeat="breed in breeds">{{breed.$t}}</div>
```

Or if you need to keep it all in the same `pet` object and not create new scope properties just use conditional to change the corresponding property to array if it isn't already

```
 if(pet.breeds.breed && !angular.isArray(pet.breeds.breed) ){
     pet.breeds.breed  = [pet.breeds.breed];       
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looping object in `ng-repeat` key name with symbols like `$` is not supported. you need to remove the `$` mark from the property

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.obj = { "pet": {
            "options": {
                "option": [{
                    "$t": "hasShots"
                }]
            },
            "status": {
                "$t": "A"
            },
            "contact": {
                "phone": {},
                "state": {
                    "$t": "NC"
                },
                "address2": {},
                "email": {
                    "$t": "deborah@rainingpets.com"
                },
                "city": {
                    "$t": "Charlotte"
                },
                "zip": {
                    "$t": "28210"
                },
                "fax": {},
                "address1": {}
            },
            "age": {
                "$t": "Adult"
            },
            "size": {
                "$t": "L"
            },
            "id": {
                "$t": "37778045"
            },
            "shelterPetId": {},
            "breeds": {
                "breed": {
                    "t": "German Shepherd Dog"
                }
            },
            "name": {
                "$t": "Axel"
            },
            "sex": {
                "$t": "M"
            },
            "description": {
                "$t": "Axel is a handsome 4-year-old German Shepherd who is looking for a home. He is a large boy weighing 95 pounds but should be closer to 80. He has the GSD prey drive and would do best with someone who is experienced with the breed. Axel is a typical Shepherd; loving, loyal and good with children. He is also playful and does need a fenced yard to play in.\n\nAxel is vaccinated, neutered and micro-chipped."
            },
            "mix": {
                "$t": "no"
            },
            "shelterId": {
                "$t": "NC880"
            },
            "lastUpdate": {
                "$t": "2017-04-08T19:31:08Z"
            },
            "animal": {
                "$t": "Dog"
            }
        }
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div class="ui label" ng-repeat="(k, breed) in obj.pet.breeds.breed">key- {{k}} <br> value-  {{breed}}</div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add below line to your controller scope, in JS file

```
$scope.isArray = angular.isArray;
```

In your view file add below check

```
<div ng-if="isArray($scope.pet.breeds)>
    -- Code for ng-repeat
</div>

 <div ng-if="!isArray($scope.pet.breeds)>
    -- Code for direct data read $scope.pet.breeds.breet.$t
</div>
```

I hop it helps.